# Generalization of spherical waves for arbitrary number of dimensions

Tags: waves, spacetime-dimensions, greens-functions

I am looking for a generalization of spherical waves

$$ [\partial_t^2 - \Delta_N] \, \psi = 0 $$

for an arbitary number of dimensions $N$.

In spherical coordinates we can write

$$ \Delta_N = \partial_r^2 + (N-1)r^{-1}\partial_r + \Delta_\Omega $$

I am interested in solutions with $r$-dependence only, i.e. vanishing derivatives w.r.t. the angular coordinates

$$ \Delta_\Omega \, \psi = 0 $$

Therefore

$$ \left[\partial_t^2 - \left( \partial_r^2 - (N-1)r^{-1}\partial_r \right) \right] \, \psi(r,t) = 0 $$

A reasonable ansatz would be

$$ \psi(r,t) = \left[ A_k(r) \, e^{ikr} + B_k(r) \, e^{-ikr} \right] e^{-i\omega t}; \quad \omega^2 - k^2 = 0$$

Questions:

1. is this ansatz valid for any $ N = 2,3, \ldots $?
2. is there a general formula for the functions $ A_k(r), B_k(r) $ for any $N$?

Comment: Why don't you write $\psi(r,t) = e^{-i\omega t} \psi(r)$ and then solve the corresponding differential equation for $\psi(r)$?

Comment: This ansatz seems to be reasonable; are you saying that this is *not* the case? It is in N=3

Comment: I am not saying that. I am saying that there's no need to make an ansatz. You can simply solve the differential equation for $\psi(r)$ and find the exact solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume time-harmonic signals, then we may write (as @Prahar suggests)
$$\psi(r,t)=e^{-i\omega t}f(r).$$
Substituting this into the $N$D wave equation yields the $N$D Helmholtz equation:
$$f'' + \frac{N-1}{r}f' + k^2f = 0,$$
where $k=\omega/c$.  According to WolframAlpha this is called the Emdem-Fowler equation, and may be solve in terms of Bessel functions as
$$f = Ar^{1-N/2}J_{\frac{N}{2}-1}(kr) + Br^{1-N/2}Y_{\frac{N}{2}-1}(kr),$$
where $A$ and $B$ are arbitrary constants, and $J_\alpha$ and $Y_\alpha$ are Bessel functions of the first and second kinds of order $\alpha$.

The ansatz you suggest comes from the choice of $N=3$, where we find
\begin{align}
  \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2kr}}J_{\frac{3}{2}-1}(kr) &= \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2kr}}J_{1/2}(kr)=j_0(kr)=\frac{\sin(kr)}{kr} =\frac{e^{ikr}-ie^{-ikr}}{2ikr}, \\
  \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2kr}}Y_{\frac{3}{2}-1}(kr) &= \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2kr}}Y_{1/2}(kr) = y_0(kr) = -\frac{\cos(kr)}{kr} = -\frac{e^{ikr}+ie^{-ikr}}{2kr}.
\end{align}
Similar trigonometric forms will arise whenever $N$ is odd.  However, when $N$ is even your proposed ansatz may lead to unnecessarily complicated functions.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot!